# how to write two different Laurent series for the following experission?

Tags: complex-analysis

f(z)=$\frac{z}{(z-i)^2}$ +$\frac{1}{z}$ centered at i.

I know that converges in |z-i|<1
we can have a laurent series only when 0<|z-z0|<R
f(z) = $\frac{a-1}{z-z0}$+$\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty$ an(z-z0)^n=$\frac{a-1}{z-z0}$+g(z)
and must be analytic g(z)
thats all I knew so now how can I apply this to the question. could you please give me some hint or tell me where to start from? giving a similar example would help a lot as well.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure about that $z-i^2$? Why not just $z+1$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes  its i though i typed wrong I am gonna edit the question now its (z-i)^2 in denominator

Comment: $f(z)$ is analytic in the entire complex plane other than $\{i,0\}$. It will have one Laurent expansion centred at $i$ that converges for $0<|z-i|<1$, and it will have a second Laurent expansion centred at $i$ that converges for $|z-i|>1$.

Comment: @GregMartin thanks good hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $|z-i|<1$, then\begin{align}\frac1z&=\frac1{i+z-i}\\&=\frac{-i}{1-i(z-i)}\\&=-i\sum_{n=0}^\infty(i(z-i))^n\\&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty i^{n+1}(z-i)^n.\end{align}On the other hand\begin{align}\frac z{(z-i)^2}&=\frac{i+(z-i)}{(z-i)^2}\\&=\frac i{(z-i)^2}+\frac1{z-i},\end{align}and therefore$$|z-i|<1\implies\frac z{(z-i)^2}+\frac1z=\frac i{(z-i)^2}+\frac1{z-i}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty i^{n+1}(z-i)^n.$$The case in which $|z-i|>1$ is similar, but in this case we se the fact that then$$\frac1{1-i(z-i)}=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}(i(z-i))^n.$$

Comment: thanks a lot so do I need to do the same thing once for 0<|z-i|<1 as well for the 2 Lauren series?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand your question.

Comment: I mean there is two cases that this could be centered at i one is |z-i|>1 and the other is 0<|z-i|<1. and the question has asked us to write two laurent series for it. one case is the one you wrote and there should be another one right? using the fact thst 0<|z-i|<1

Comment: The one that I wrote is the case in which $0<|z-i|<1$. And, yes, there is another one for the case in whcih $|z-i|>1$. I explained in the last sentence of my answer what should be done to get the answer in that case.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos  oh yeah makes sense thanks a lot